# Collect data from multiple worksheets in one new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to append data from column AG1 on multiple worksheets in one new worksheet.
(ex: worksheet1 to column A, worksheet2 to column B, etc.).

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("AG2:AG5000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Try").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Sheets2.Activate
    Range("AG2:AG5000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Try").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

So far, I just can use macro from "record macro".

---

The problems are:
(1) number of sheets is always different,
(2) name of every sheet is always different.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include the code you have come up with so far in your question.

Comment: "to one row in new sheet" does not match to "worksheet1 to column A, ...". What do you want "Combine"? Rows or columns? Does this "Combine" mean copying each column in a new sheet?

Comment: @braX im sorry, forgot to input my code

Comment: @FaneDuru my mistake, im sorry

Comment: @FaneDuru maybe the correct word is "collect". Yeah, i try to copy 1 range of all existing sheets in sheet "Try". Maybe i have to learn about macros first, before i put question in here but i dont know what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes.

```
Sub CopyFromMultiple()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim pColumn As Long

pColumn = 1
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "Try" Then
            sh.Range("AG2:AG5000").Copy Sheets("Try").Cells(1, pColumn)
            pColumn = pColumn + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub testCollectingColData()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shTr As Worksheet, arr As Variant, colNo As Long
 
 Set shTr = Worksheets("Try")
 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> shTr.Name Then
        colNo = colNo + 1
        arr = sh.Range("AG2:AG5000").Value
        shTr.Range(shTr.cells(1, colNo), shTr.cells(5000 - 1, colNo)).Value = arr
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```